# Nginx server is not running in centos7

Tags: nginx, centos7

The below error is coming while run the command sudo `nginx -t`

how can i get resolve out this problem?

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/certs/bc0caaf684d122e1.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/bc0caaf684d122e1.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: The cert file is not exist.

Comment: doe any file`bc0caaf684d122e1.crt` in `/etc/ssl/certs/bc0caaf684d122e1.crt`?